# How to add youtube videos to custom UITableViewCell using UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I would like to display few webpages using `UIWebView` and a `label` which are on a custom table cell.

I have succeeded in getting different names for different `cell` but I am getting same `url` in each custom `cell`. How can I get different `URL`s for different cells?

```
//MyCustomCell.h

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *myWebView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *websiteNameLabel;
@property NSString *websiteURLString;

//MyCustomCell.m
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    // Initialization code
    self.websiteURLString = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
    NSURLRequest *request1 = [NSURL URLWithString:self.websiteURLString];
    [[self myWebView]loadRequest:request1];

    self.websiteURLString = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.gmail.com"];
    NSURLRequest *request2 = [NSURL URLWithString:self.websiteURLString];
    [[self myWebView]loadRequest:request2];

    self.websiteURLString = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.facebook.com"];
    NSURLRequest *request3 = [NSURL URLWithString:self.websiteURLString];
    [[self myWebView]loadRequest:request3];
}

//MyViewController.h
@property NSMutableArray *webPageNameArray;
@property NSString *googleWebURL,*yahooWebURL,*facebookWebURL;

//MyViewController.m
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib. 
    self.webPageNameArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"google",@"gmail",@"facebook", nil];  
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 3;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *identifier = @"myCell";
    StudentCustomCell *cell = (StudentCustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"StudentCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell.websiteNameLabel.text = [self.webPageNameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Please add some code

Comment: Hi, Azat i've added my code, please help. thank you.

Comment: Sorry, but your question was put on hold as too broad, and I don't have enough reputation to reopen it so I can't actually answer it. But right now I can suggest to assign `websiteURLString` as well as `websiteNameLabel` in `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: Please take a look at this link -> https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper

Comment: Generally speaking, it's a bad idea to have a tableview of `uiwebviews`... Just having one is expensive enough.

Comment: AlvinVarghese thanks for the link, i've tried installing cocoapods but that's not done. even the code sample that was provided in the page few errors. unable to rectify them.

any how my ultimate aim is to display a tableview with different youtube videos along with relevant name label. i've achieved it through code modifications done by Azat

but now my question is as i'm displaying UIWebView i need to disable scroll feature in webview and the webview should appear like a thumbnail and on click it should play video (ofcourse that's happning now)

Answer (score 0):

Delete your code from `-awakeFromNib` at `MyCustomCell.m` then replace code at `MyViewController.m` with the following:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    self.webPageNameArray = [ @"google", @"gmail", @"facebook" ];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.webPageNameArray.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *identifier = @"myCell";
    StudentCustomCell *cell = (StudentCustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if (!cell)
    {
        UINib *headerNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"StudentCustomCell" bundle:nil];
        NSArray *aNib = [headerNib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
        cell = [aNib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell.websiteNameLabel.text = self.webPageNameArray[indexPath.row];
    NSString *websiteURLString = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.%@.com", self.webPageNameArray[indexPath.row]]];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURL URLWithString:websiteURLString];
    [cell.myWebView loadRequest:request];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: thanks for improving the code that really helped but not completely by slightly modifying it. check the modified code below.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",cell.websiteURLString]];
NSURLRequest *myRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[cell.myWebView loadRequest:myRequest];
```